# Python - AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'rank'

Tags: python, attr

I'm working on different Project Euler problems through writing code on my own and watching [Youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cg5m2HGx-oM&list=PLNEKkZrJ3NV-wNjCMxPS86sgqOgwBZmPu&index=4).

While working on problem 54, the code that the author of the Youtube video wrote while defining a function in Python 2.7 is

```
def __init__(self, *args):
    self.cards = sorted(args, key=lambda c: -c.rank)
    self.duplicates = {}
    for card in self.cards:
        if card.rank in self.duplicates:
            continue
        _duplicates = 0
        for card2 in self.cards:
            if card.rank == card2.rank:
                _duplicates += 1
        self.duplicates[card.rank] = _duplicates
```

which seems to work fine for him. When I run this code on Python 3.0, my Pycharm compiler returns

```
File "C:/Users/Matthew/PycharmProjects/Project_Euler/Euler54.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.cards = sorted(args, key=lambda c: -c.rank)
  File "C:/Users/Matthew/PycharmProjects/Project_Euler/Euler54.py", line 51, in <lambda>
    self.cards = sorted(args, key=lambda c: -c.rank)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'rank'
```

I have tried changing

```
self.cards = sorted(args, key=lambda c: -c.rank)
```

to

```
self.cards = sorted(args, key=lambda c: -c.rank())
```

but this appears to be an incorrect fix. I'm not sure how to resolve this error on my own. I could look into writing a different solution, as the strategy shown by the author of the video wasn't friendly to a beginner. The full program is pasted below (I'm not sure if I should include this as I'm not formally looking for a code review. I'm trying to get the program to run so that I can complete the exercise).

```
import time
from collections import namedtuple

start = time.time()

Card = namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit'])

Ace = 14
King = 13
Queen = 12
Jack = 11
Ten = 10


def map_rank(rank_to_map):
    if rank_to_map == 'A':
        return Ace
    if rank_to_map == 'K':
        return King
    if rank_to_map == 'Q':
        return Queen
    if rank_to_map == 'J':
        return Jack
    if rank_to_map == 'T':
        return Ten
    return int(rank_to_map)


def map_suit(suit_to_map):
    if suit_to_map == 'H':
        return 1
    if suit_to_map == 'D':
        return 2
    if suit_to_map == 'C':
        return 3
    # S = Spades
    return 4


def map_card(card_to_map):
    return Card(rank=map_rank(card_to_map[0]), suit=map_suit(card_to_map[1]))


class Hand(object):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.cards = sorted(args, key=lambda c: -c.rank)
        self.duplicates = {}
        for card in self.cards:
            if card.rank in self.duplicates:
                continue
            _duplicates = 0
            for card2 in self.cards:
                if card.rank == card2.rank:
                    _duplicates += 1
            self.duplicates[card.rank] = _duplicates

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        for rule in self.rules():
            rule = getattr(self, rule)
            val = rule(other)
            if val:
                return val

    def rules(self):
        return []

    def _straight(self):
        last_card_rank = False
        for card in self.cards:
            if last_card_rank and last_card_rank != card.rank + 1:
                return False
            last_card_rank = card.rank
        return True

    def _flush(self):
        last_card_suit = False
        for card in self.cards:
            if last_card_suit and last_card_suit != card.suit:
                return False
            last_card_suit = card.suit
        return True

    def _duplicate_count(self, c):
        for rank, value in self.duplicates.items():
            if value == c:
                yield rank


class PokerHand(Hand):
    def rules(self):
        rules = super(PokerHand, self).rules()
        rules.append('royal_flush')
        rules.append('straight_flush')
        rules.append('four_of_a_kind')
        rules.append('full_house')
        rules.append('flush')
        rules.append('straight')
        rules.append('three_of_a_kind')
        rules.append('two_pair')
        rules.append('highest_card')
        return rules

    def royal_flush(self, other):
        h1 = self.cards[0].rank == Ace and self._flush() and self._straight()
        h2 = other.cards[0].rank == Ace and other._flush() and other._straight()
        if h1 and not h2:
            return 1
        if h2 and not h1:
            return -1
        if h1 and h2:
            return 0

    def straight_flush(self, other):
        h1 = self._flush() and self._straight()
        h2 = other._flush() and other._straight()
        if h1 and not h2:
            return 1
        if h2 and not h1:
            return -1
        if h1 and h2:
            return self.highest_card(other)

    def four_of_a_kind(self, other):
        return self._of_a_kind(other, 4)

    def three_of_a_kind(self, other):
        return self._of_a_kind(other, 3)

    def _of_a_kind(self, other, value):
        h1 = [r for r in self._duplicate_count(value)]
        h2 = [r for r in other._duplicate_count(value)]
        if len(h1) > len(h2):
            return 1
        if len(h2) > len(h1):
            return -1
        for h1_c, h2_c in zip(h1, h2):
            if h1_c > h2_c:
                return 1
            if h2_c > h1_c:
                return -1

    def two_pair(self, other):
        return self._of_a_kind(other, 2)

    def full_house(self, other):
        h1_3 = [r for r in self._duplicate_count(3)]
        h2_3 = [r for r in other._duplicate_count(3)]
        h1_2 = [r for r in self._duplicate_count(2)]
        h2_2 = [r for r in other._duplicate_count(2)]
        if h1_3 and h1_2 and not (h2_3 and h2_2):
            return 1
        if h2_3 and h2_2 and not (h1_3 and h1_2):
            return -1
        if h1_3 and h1_2 and h2_3 and h2_2:
            for h1_c, h2_c in zip(h1_3, h2_3):
                if h1_c > h2_c:
                    return 1
                if h2_c > h1_c:
                    return -1
            for h1_c, h2_c in zip(h1_2, h2_2):
                if h1_c > h2_c:
                    return 1
                if h2_c > h1_c:
                    return -1

    def flush(self, other):
        h1 = self._flush
        h2 = other._flush
        if h1 and not h2:
            return 1
        if h2 and not h1:
            return -1
        if h1 and h2:
            return self.highest_card(other)

    def straight(self, other):
        h1 = self._straight
        h2 = other._straight
        if h1 and not h2:
            return 1
        if h2 and not h1:
            return -1
        if h1 and h2:
            return self.highest_card(other)

    def highest_card(self, other):
        for c1,c2 in zip(self.cards, other.cards):
            if c1.rank != c2.rank:
                return 1 if c1.rank > c2.rank else -1
        raise Exception("tie in highest_card")


def gen_hands(s):
    cards = [map_card for c in s.split(' ')]
    return PokerHand(*cards[0:5]), PokerHand(*cards[5:])

p1_wins = 0
with open('poker.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        h1, h2 = gen_hands(line.strip())
        if h1 > h2:
            p1_wins += 1
print(p1_wins)
```

The program won't run as pasted without adding the poker.txt file provided [here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=54). Please let me know if it was a mistake to create a post for this sort of attribute error on SE. I wasn't sure if I should post code for Project Euler on this site.

Comment: From error, the problem is with: `c.rank`.  `c` is apparently a function, where as it should be some sort of object or instance which has a `rank` attribute.  Did you forget a pair of `()`, which would evaluate the function?

Comment: The line `cards = [map_card for c in s.split(' ')]` generates a list containing a bunch of references to the `map_card` function.  The actual contents of your string `s` has no effect, other than setting the length of that list.  You probably want `map_card(c)` in there.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That was the problem indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 195,

```
cards = [map_card for c in s.split(' ')]
```

in

```
def gen_hands(s):
        cards = [map_card for c in s.split(' ')]
        return PokerHand(*cards[0:5]), PokerHand(*cards[5:])
```

generates a list containing a large amount of references to the `map_card` function. This was mistakenly written as `map_card` instead of `map_card(c)`. It should be

```
def gen_hands(s):
    cards = [map_card(c) for c in s.split(' ')]
    return PokerHand(*cards[0:5]), PokerHand(*cards[5:])
```